# Is there any tiling WM with graphical effects support?

Tags: window-manager

I know, that programmer's happiness is not about rich 3D-effects of windows manager. But all tiling WMs that I've find looks like really old-school.

And my question:
**Is there any tiling WM not necessarily with rich 3D-effects but at least with qualitatively drawed panels and some animation?**

*I ask it of tiling WM, not plugin to use composing WM as tiling.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've not tried either of these hacks myself, but here's what I found when I was asking myself just the same question:

### 1 - Franken-XMonad-Compiz

Someone called *tuxmark5*, who afterwards "promptly disappeared" [mashed together XMonad and Compiz [YouTube]](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hxpzNGppcbs), presumably using something magical and dirty in `XMonad.Hooks.*` in a way that looks just like what you describe. There are some potentially useful links in the video description and you could try PM-ing the uploader.

### 2 - Compiz plug-in

[This guy wrote a tiling plugin for Compiz](http://suasol.wordpress.com/2008/06/28/new-tiling-plugin-for-compiz-fusion-grid/), but "you’ll need a boatload of dependencies to make it compile", he cautions. Comments to the blog post say things like "*it does work great*", "*absolutely fantastically great*" and "*uber plugin*", which sounds ridiculously promising! (Though not promising enough for me to grab a boatload of dependencies. Let me know if you try it!)